# Cannot updated from Spring Boots 1.4 to 1.5.10

Tags: spring-boot

> ws/src/test/java/com/db/sdrws/integration/test/KacTest.java:[9,37]
>   package org.springframework.boot.test does not exist [ERROR]
>   /H:/git/vgp-sdr-ws/src/test/java/com/db/sdrws/integration/test/KacTest.java:[28,2]
>   cannot find symbol.   symbol: class SpringApplicationConfiguration

It seems `SpringApplicationConfiguration` has been deprecated. What is an alternative for this class?

Answer (score 0):

That class was already deprecated in Spring Boot 1.4 and has, accordingly, been removed in the next major version 1.5. What to do is actually in the [javadoc of `SpringApplicationConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html).

> **Deprecated.** 
>   as of 1.4 in favor of `SpringBootTest` or direct use of `SpringBootContextLoader`. (From the [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html)).

Comment: Hi M.Deinum i did changes, but  i used @SpringBootsContextLoader classes =application.class error is can not resolved methods classes

Comment: Just use `@SpringBootTest` no need to use the additional classes attribute.

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

Comment: Hi M.deinum could you please suggest here